# MVC: how do I pass an array from a model to a view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

The `$task` array is displayed in the model as follows:

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [0] => 1 
    [name] => Nicolas IV 
    [2] => Nicolas IV 
    [email] => breitenberg.dedrick@example.com 
    [3] => breitenberg.dedrick@example.com 
...
```

But the view task_show.php returns an error:

```
Undefined variable: task
```

please tell me what is wrong with my code?

**Controller**

```
<?php
  class Index extends Controller{
   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->view->render('index/index');
     require 'models/index_model.php';
   }
   public function task_show($id = false) {
     $tasks = Index_Model::task_show($id);
     require 'views/index/task_show.php';
   }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
  class Index_Model extends Model{

    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
    }
    public function task_show($id) {
      $db = new Database();
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?");
      $stmt->execute([$id]);
      $task = $stmt->fetch();
      print_r ($task);
      return $task;
    }
  }
```

**View**

```
 <?php echo $task['name']; ?>
```

Comment: Cal that method in controller. Put result in variable $someName, and then include that view.php in controller. You actually done it but you have $tasks in controller and $task in view.

Comment: either change `$tasks = Index_Model::task_show($id);` to `$task = Index_Model::task_show($id);` or `echo $task['name'];` to `echo $tasks['name'];` and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I will expand my comment because I space for few advices:
This code:

```
public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
        }
```

In you model does nothing. Remove it.
This way:

```
$tasks = Index_Model::task_show($id);
```

You call static method which

```
public function task_show($id) {
```

is not.

And work with errors on, It would tell you what's wrong, at least in some cases.In the top of file you want to investigate place

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```